# How do I make a COM object in regards to MFC or MFC ActiveX Control in C++?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, com, atl

For my job, I am supposed to make a COM object for a video player that utilizes SDL and ffmpeg libaries. The COM object is supposed to embed the video player into a C# application. The code I will be writing will be in C++. In regards to COM objects, I have researched on using MFC, ATL and I have already done a few tutorials on YouTube in regards to creating simple COM objects but they were mainly in ATL so I don't have any experience using MFC. I am using Visual Studios Professional 2015. I still don't understand COM objects fully since many of the definitions are high level.

One of my questions is, in regards to this project I am working on, what is the best way to create a COM object for this situation? I know ATL is not GUI-oriented but MFC is, but I don't know if I can still use ATL for this situation or not. I'm very new to all of this, and I'm confused as to what MFC ActiveX Control does. From what my understanding is, you use it to process events which makes me think it isn't write for this project. I am honestly in a nutshell with all this and I would appreciate any help.

Secondly, depending on if I have to learn ATL or MFC for COM objects, is it possible to get a more in-depth example program for one of these, or possibly to teach me this. It is hard enough to understand articles since they are old and high level, but I can't seem to find tutors that know this, so I'm willing to pay for teaching me this.

Thanks

Comment: MFC (developed for desktop app/GUI) was developed first. ATL was then made more for server side COM, so it's more simple/raw. But it was expanded and has some GUI support too. Learning COM is not easy and as you say, there are not much resources today (while the technology is far from being legacy). If you don't need too much GUI, I would start with ATL. Plus all that is open source, you *will* have to take a deep breath and dive in it. As for learning COM and ATL, I would recommend Wrox old books: Professional COM applications with ATL, Professional ATL COM prog., Beginning ATL COM prog.

Comment: You should continue to use VS2015 until you have the know-how to develop COM components without the Wizard. The Wizard related to ATL/MFC is broken in VS2017 and not included in VS2019. [The big ATL wizard misery](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289506/the-big-atl-wizard-misery.html), [Deprecations - Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.0#-deprecations)